# summernote editor - while typing english cursor moves to the top

Tags: cursor, editor, summernote

Every time I type in English in summernote, the cursor moves to the top.
I'm using koranLang.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFtRI.png)

`JQuery.extend(JQuery.summernote.lang, { 'ko-KR': koreanLang });`

how can i solve this problem?
Every time I type in English in summernote, the cursor moves to the top.